# PostgreSQL error function width_bucket(timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time zone[]) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Already solved problem - posting in here because solution eluded me until I translated this Chinese [blog post](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&u=https%3A%2F%2Fbilltian.github.io%2Fdigoal.blog%2F2015%2F06%2F16%2F01.html).

```
ERROR:  function width_bucket(timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone[]) does not exist
LINE 3:     width_bucket(
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

or

```
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  function width_bucket(timestamp with time zone, timestamp without time zone[]) does not exist
LINE 3: width_bucket(
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to specify time zone (i.e. `with time zone` below) in your series generator:

```
select generate_series(
       timestamp with time zone '2020-10-02 13:43:00', 
       '2020-10-17 16:15:00', 
       '12 hours'))
```

.. or indeed `without time zone` is that matches the data you're binning with the series.  Use `select pg_typeof(timecolumn) from table limit 1;` to report whether your data notionally uses time zone.